# How does Google's SafeSearch affect SEO?

Tags: seo, google, moderation

Sorry, I am using a profanity below.

I am observing the following behaviour:

1. SafeSearch ON, search "fucka": amazon.com is a first result.
2. SafeSearch ON, search "a": amazon.com is a sixth result.
3. SafeSearch OFF, search "fucka": amazon.com is not even on the first page.
4. SafeSearch OFF, search "a": amazon.com is a sixth result.

Is there an objective explanation? I could not find anything.

Comment: I have no idea, but I am curious too! Since my website exists of bad domains (domain name) primarily, you would guess that a lot of them could be effected by what you are seeing. I am curious about your test sample above. What was the motivation in choosing these search terms or are the one example of several.

Comment: @closetnoc Sometimes I just search for random words :). Was mainly expecting an Urban Dictionary definition at the top.

Comment: Okay! 8-) I was not sure if there was a particular effect you were trying to chase down or just like I do from time to time- goofing off. Everyone makes queries out of curiosity that are kind of random.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon is a "safe" site.   That is why it appears when safe search is turned on.   My guess is that somebody has linked to Amazon with the anchor text like "Fuck that big retailer that starts with A".  That is why Google is showing Amazon for that query.

With safe search off, there are many more relevant sites that Google is allowed to show you.   That is why Amazon is pushed off the front page of the search results.